# Hibernate Sub query inside case when statement

Tags: hibernate, subquery, case

I'm having a problem on executing HQL sub query inside case when statement.

here is my code:

```
select case when a.entityId is null then 'invalid' else 
   (select b.entityName from tblName b where b.entityId =a.entityId) 
   end from tblEntity a
```

Thanks for any help!

Ok.. here's the full stack trace

```
ERROR org.hibernate.hql.PARSER - <AST>:0:0: unexpected AST node: query
Exception in thread "Thread-5" org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: query [select case when a.entityId is null then 'invalid' else 
       (select b.entityName from tblName b where b.entityId =a.entityId) 
       end from tblEntity a]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1651)
```

Comment: what error is it giving?

Comment: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node

Comment: still no clue! Edit the question,and add the **complete stack trace**!

Comment: Thanks for the response! ...when I use the subquery with out the case when, it works, but when I use it inside a case when statement then it won't work.

Answer (score 4):

This feature is not supported in Hibernate. 
But there does exist a workaround.
Create a view in the database and then use HQL to fetch result through java.

create or replace force view VW_ENTITY_VALUE(entityValue)
as
select case when a.entityId is null then 'invalid' else 
   (select b.entityName from tblName b where b.entityId =a.entityId) 
   end from tblEntity a;

From documentation of HQL:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries

14.13. Subqueries

For databases that support subselects, Hibernate supports subqueries within queries. A subquery must be surrounded by parentheses (often by an SQL aggregate function call). Even correlated subqueries (subqueries that refer to an alias in the outer query) are allowed.

from Cat as fatcat
where fatcat.weight > (
    select avg(cat.weight) from DomesticCat cat
)
from DomesticCat as cat
where cat.name = some (
    select name.nickName from Name as name
)
from Cat as cat
where not exists (
    from Cat as mate where mate.mate = cat
)
from DomesticCat as cat
where cat.name not in (
    select name.nickName from Name as name
)
select cat.id, (select max(kit.weight) from cat.kitten kit)
from Cat as cat
***Note that HQL subqueries can occur only in the select or where clauses.***